# Call code on interrupting Unity animator sub-FSM

Tags: unity, animation

I'm trying to find a way to execute a code when one of two outcomes happens in **Unity animator controller**:

1. When animator's sub-FSM finishes or
2. When animator's sub-FSM is "interrupted" by a transition originating from "Any state" node at the parent FSM.

The concrete setup is next (but that is probably not super important):

The parent FSM have a transition from "Any state" to Damaged state and that can "interrupt" an attack sub-FSM: [Parent FSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlVSe.png)

The attack sub-FSM consists of three states that run in succession PreAttack -> Attack -> PostAttack: [Attack sub-FSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufcWG.png)

At the end of the attack sub-FSM a method is called. It can be through:

1. Animation even at the end of PostAttack animation in the sub-FSM, or
2. StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateExit() at the PostAttack state , or
3. StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateMachineExit() at the sub-FSM.

The problem is that none of these 3 is called when the sub-FSM is "interrupted" by the "Any state" transition in the parent. Is there any way to call code when a sub-FSM is "interrupted" by "Any state" transition in the parent FSM?